# Closed form for this $\text{I}=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\pi^{nx}-1}\space\text{d}x$ integral? (spot my mistake)

Tags: integration, limits

Solving [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587045/a-contest-math-integral-int-1-infty-frac-textdx-pinx-1), I came up with this (but mathematica says, there isn't a closed form) can someone spot my mistake?

My work:

Assume that $m$ and $n$ are positive $\to m,n\in\mathbb{R^+}$:

$$\text{I}=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\pi^{nx}-1}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\int_{1}^{m}\frac{1}{\pi^{nx}-1}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Substitute $u=nx$ and $\text{d}u=n\space\text{d}x$:

This gives a new lower bound $u=n\cdot1=n$ and upper bound $u=n\cdot m=mn$:

---

$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_{n}^{mn}\frac{1}{\pi^{u}-1}\space\text{d}u=$$

---

Substitute $s=\pi^u$ and $\text{d}s=\pi^u\ln(\pi)\space\text{d}u$:

This gives a new lower bound $s=\pi^{n}$ and upper bound $s=\pi^{mn}$:

---

$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln(\pi)}\int_{\pi^{n}}^{\pi^{mn}}\frac{1}{s(s-1)}\space\text{d}s=$$
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln(\pi)}\int_{\pi^{n}}^{\pi^{mn}}\left(\frac{1}{s-1}-\frac{1}{s}\right)\space\text{d}s=$$
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln(\pi)}\left(\int_{\pi^{n}}^{\pi^{mn}}\frac{1}{s-1}\space\text{d}s-\int_{\pi^{n}}^{\pi^{mn}}\frac{1}{s}\space\text{d}s\right)=$$
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln(\pi)}\left(\int_{\pi^{n}}^{\pi^{mn}}\frac{1}{s-1}\space\text{d}s-\left[\ln\left|s\right|\right]_{\pi^{n}}^{\pi^{mn}}\right)=$$

---

Substitute $p=s-1$ and $\text{d}p=\text{d}s$:

This gives a new lower bound $p=\pi^{n}-1$ and upper bound $p=\pi^{mn}-1$:

---

$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln(\pi)}\left(\int_{\pi^{n}-1}^{\pi^{mn}-1}\frac{1}{p}\space\text{d}p-\left[\ln\left|s\right|\right]_{\pi^{n}}^{\pi^{mn}}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln(\pi)}\left(\left[\ln\left|p\right|\right]_{\pi^{n}-1}^{\pi^{mn}-1}-\left[\ln\left|s\right|\right]_{\pi^{n}}^{\pi^{mn}}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left|\pi^{mn}-1\right|-\ln\left|\pi^{n}-1\right|-\ln\left|\pi^{mn}\right|+\ln\left|\pi^{n}\right|}{n\ln(\pi)}=$$
$$\frac{1}{n\ln(\pi)}\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\ln\left|\pi^{mn}-1\right|-\ln\left|\pi^{n}-1\right|-\ln\left|\pi^{mn}\right|+\ln\left|\pi^{n}\right|\right)=$$
$$\frac{1}{n\ln(\pi)}\lim_{m\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{\pi^n-\pi^{n-mn}}{\pi^n-1}\right)=\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{\pi^n-1}\right)}{n\ln(\pi)}$$

Comment: I don't think there is a mistake.

Comment: @Hamed Than mathematica is wrong, because there is a closed form!

Comment: Isn't it already proven in the linked problem that there is a closed form?

Comment: I saw this comment under the linked problem (and I think that,that is wrong): @Sky It converges for n≥0

Comment: @JanEerland Mathematica indeed gives you the answer. Try the following: Integrate[1/(Pi^(n x) - 1), {x, 1, Infinity}, Assumptions -> n > 0] if you are intrested.

Comment: @HartoSaarinen Yes, I've checked it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the correct answer (although in a roundabout fashion). The problem probably comes from not telling Mathematica what $n$ is: if you don't tell it than $n>0$ (which you seem to be assuming), then it may not come up with the right assumptions by itself.

As a simpler way of doing it, set $\pi^n=a$. Then
$$ I=\int_1^{\infty} \frac{dx}{a^x-1} = \frac{1}{\log{a}}\int_a^{\infty} \frac{du}{u(u-1)} = \frac{1}{\log{a}} \int_a^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{u-1}-\frac{1}{u} \right) du. $$
Now do the limit definition:
$$ I\log{a}=\lim_{m \to \infty} \int_a^m \left( \frac{1}{u-1}-\frac{1}{u} \right) du = \lim_{m \to \infty} [\log{(u-1)}-\log{u}]_a^m \\
= \lim_{m\to\infty} \log{\left( 1-\frac{1}{m} \right)}-\log{\left(1-\frac{1}{a}\right)}. $$
Clearly taking the limit gives
$$ I = \frac{-\log{(1-1/a)}}{\log{a}}, $$
which you can then stick $a=\pi^n$ into and rearrange to your heart's desire.